# Laptop stuck at 'Shutting down' on starting with the loading circle rotating

Tags: laptop, windows-10, shutdown

I was using my laptop (HP 2000). Meanwhile, the battery drained out and it went off. When I plugged the charger and turned the laptop on, it never started.

It was stuck at Shutting down screen with that moving circle there:

[image]

Comment: Try a forced shutdown - press and hold the power button until the laptop powers off - then restart it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It is stuck at Shutting down screen with that moving circle there

You need to do a "Forced Shutdown":

- Press and hold the power button until the laptop powers off
- Press the power button again to restart the laptop.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to a netbook which was using a separate monitor.  Start up just showed the circle on a blue background with the 'shutting down' message. Switching off at the power button and then restarting fairly quickly did not help the situation.

Switching off at the power button and keeping the button pushed down until the shut down process turned the monitor off completely (quite a long time), has fixed the problem.

Turning the netbook on in the normal way after that, no problem, fixed !